# Unique Membership Number in Access Database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a Database in Access 2010 where the 1st field is a unique membership number. The field is set Indexed, no duplicates. If a duplicate is entered on the input form no error message is displayed and nothing else works until a unique number is entered. I need the code that would trap the error on the number field losing focus so that a message box would tell the user the problem and then set focus back to the number field or let the user cancel all input. 
This is what I have and it causes Datatype errors

```vb
Private Sub Grumpy_No_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)  
    If DLookup(Str("[Grumpy_No]"), "Grumpy", Str("[Grumpy_No]") = Me!Str(Grumpy_No)) Then   
    MsgBox "Number has already been entered in the database."   
    Cancel = True  
    Me!Grumpy_No.Undo   
    End If   
End Sub
```

Any clues as to where I am going wrong would be very much appreciated

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for the [TextBox.BeforeUpdate Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845199.aspx)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but I am quite new to Access. I can see that you are right about BeforeUpdate Event but it appears to only want to work with character fields not an Integer. I have tried the STR() function but keep getting Data type errors. I should explain my club is a motorbike club called "Grumpy Old Bastards" the table is "Grumpy" and the field is "Grumpy_No" which is an Integer.

Comment: This is what I have :-    Private Sub Grumpy_No_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
 If DLookup(Str("[Grumpy_No]"), "Grumpy", Str("[Grumpy_No]") = Me!Str(Grumpy_No)) Then
 MsgBox "Number has already been entered in the database."
 Cancel = True
 Me!Grumpy_No.Undo
 End If
 
End Sub
Any clues as to where I am going wrong would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you're heading in the right direction but you need to fix your `DLookup` expression.  Its third argument must be a single string.  I don't see why `Str()` is useful --- just build a string.  Actually I would use `DCount` instead of `DLookup`, but then the same issues still apply.

```vb
Private Sub Grumpy_No_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)  
    If DCount("[Grumpy_No]", "Grumpy", "[Grumpy_No] = " & Me!Grumpy_No.Value) > 0 Then   
        MsgBox "Number has already been entered in the database."   
        Cancel = True  
        'Me!Grumpy_No.Undo '<- consider allowing the user to see the value which failed
    End If   
End Sub
```

Note, if you can make `Grumpy_No` an autonumber primary key, Access will supply unique values automagically, so you wouldn't need your own code to check those values.

Comment: Just what I needed HansUp I now have this   Private Sub Grumpy_No_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)  
    Dim NewNum As String
    NewNum = Str(Me!Grumpy_No.Value)
    
    If Me!Grumpy_No.Value > 0 Then
    
        If DCount("[Grumpy_No]", "Grumpy", "[Grumpy_No] = " & Me!Grumpy_No.Value) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Grumpy Number " + NewNum + " has already been entered in the database."
            Cancel = True
            Me!Grumpy_No.Undo '
        End If
    
    End If
End Sub

Comment: The only trouble now is that after it runs the routine (which works just how I wanted it to) I now get an Access error message saying "The Value Violates The Validation Rule For The Field Or Record"  I thought it might be the No Duplicates in the Table so I changed it to Duplicates OK but I still get the Error. I can't find any validation rules anywhere else.

Comment: Nuts!  That's another problem, Ray.  And I suspect that problem is independant of the form so you would get the same error when attempting to add a new row to the table when it is open in Datasheet View.  I think your best move now is to submit a new question which describes the current problem.

Comment: Good news and bad. Removing the "Required" from the table solves it. Now I have to trap the Empty field when they click the "Save" button. Can't thank you enough for all your help and advice.